# I keep getting a type error and don't know why

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def printWord(a,b):
    a= raw_input ("What would you like me to say?")
    b= raw_input ("How many times would you like me to say it?")
    int(float(b))
    for i in range(b):
        print a
```

this code keeps giving me this error:

```
line 10, in printWord
  for i in range(b):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

Comment: Because `b` is a string, but `range` expects an integer.

Comment: all the data-type constructors like `int`, `float`, and `str` *don't change the underlying object*. They just create a new object and return it. So, if you don't assign the result of that to some variable, or save it in some data structure (like a `list`), then it will become unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea with this line:

```
int(float(b))
```

but that doesn't change b in-place. You have to keep the result. Use this:

```
b = int(float(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `int(float(b))` does not change the state of b. After that line b is still a string, while range() expects an integer. I might change that line to `b = int(b)` to modify b to what you need it to be.